# exporting table from R

Tags: org-export, r

I'm trying to export a table from an R code block and have read [Results of Evaluation (The Org Manual)](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html#Results-of-Evaluation) which states that tables can be output with header options of `:exports results :results value table`.

To get the table in the correct format I'm using the R package `toOrg` function from [orgutils](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/orgutils/).

Unfortunately it doesn't appear to work with this simple example...

```
#+STARTUP: align
#+TITLE: Test
#+AUTHOR: Me
#+PROPERTY: header-args:R :session *org-R*
#+PROPERTY: header-args:R :cache yes
#+PROPERTY: header-args:R :results graphics
#+PROPERTY: header-args:R :width 1024
#+PROPERTY: header-args:R :height 768
#+PROPERTY: header-args:R :tangle yes


#+begin_src R :session *org-R* :eval yes :exports none :results output silent
  library(orgutils)
  library(tidyverse)
#+end_src


#+begin_src R :session *org-R* :eval yes :exports both :results value table
  employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
  salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
  startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
  employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)
  employ.data %>%
    toOrg()
#+end_src
```

Compiling to HTML I only get the code, no table is shown in the Org buffer itself (figures are shown inline) and no table in the resulting HTML.

If I execute just the R code within an R session it prints...

```
> employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
> salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
> startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
> employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)
>  employ.data %>%
    toOrg()
| employee   | salary | startdate  |
|------------+--------+------------|
| John Doe   |  21000 | 2010-11-01 |
| Peter Gynn |  23400 | 2008-03-25 |
| Jolie Hope |  26800 | 2007-03-14 |
```

Really can't see what I'm doing wrong here and any pointers would be gratefully received.

Comment: I think you just need to actually [evaluate the code block](https://orgmode.org/manual/Evaluating-Code-Blocks.html#Evaluating-Code-Blocks) so that the result is inserted into the org file.  If you then export to HTML, the table should be included.

Comment: Thanks @loris for your time, @Philopolis assessment got me over the line, I was over complicating things trying to use the `orgutils` package.

Comment: With `:exports both` (or just `:exports results`) , the exprorter will do the evaluation of the code block during export, so it should not need to be done beforehand. OTOH, evaluating the code block is a good test that everything works *before* you try the export (where problems in the code evaluation might be hidden). IOW, code evaluation is not necessary with the right `:exports` header, but it is a good debugging technique nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, two remarks: your example is not perfectly reproducible (you do not import the convenient R library for the `%>%` operator, and there is a typo in the header of your second src block). I don't know whether this explains everything, but this might explain a part of your problem.

Not sure of why you need an external R package for such a simple example. Using the standard org mode approach, this just works:

```
#+begin_src R :session *org-R* :exports both :results value table :colnames yes
  employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
  salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
  startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
  employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)
  employ.data
#+end_src
```

Otherwise, if you really want to use this package, then the result-type should not be a `value`; it should be `raw output` instead. The following src block is perfectly equivalent to the previous one:

```
#+begin_src R :session *org-R* :exports both :results output raw :colnames yes
  employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
  salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
  startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
  employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)
  toOrg(employ.data)
#+end_src
```

Comment: Apologies for omitting to import one of the libraries (`library(tidyverse)`) added (already had an R session running with it loaded).  You are right this is a simple example, I'm trying to do something more complex with R but created an example rather than posting my whole problem.  Going with the standard org mode approach you've recommended works as does `raw output`, thank you for taking the time to help me out.